# Reading gmail from c#

Tags: c#, imap, gmail-imap

Does anyone know a way to read email messages from a gmail account in C#? I've looked for hours and found a few options that all seemed to have been broken by Google's change in protocol however long ago. I've tried POP3 and IMAP and none seem to work.

For some reason OpenSSL.NET won't load, giving me this error "Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedOpenSsl, Version=0.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." so solving that problem would also be a solution to my troubles

Can anyone solve the problem of OpenSSL (I assume it has to do with where to put libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll, I tried in /bin and where the program exists) or provide another solution of reading emails from GMail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IMAP. See:

[Count number of emails in gmail using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539692/count-number-of-emails-in-gmail-using-imap/3539700#3539700)