# How to count number of emails in my GMail Inbox using Version 3.5 of the IMAPX 2

Tags: c#, gmail, console-application, imap

I want to count the number of emails I have in my GMail inbox using [IMAPX](https://imapx.codeplex.com/). Here is what I have written so far:

```
if (client.Connect()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Connected Successfully.");
  if (client.Login("MyEmai, "MyPassword")) {
    Folder inbox = client.Folders.Inbox;
    int count = inbox.Messages.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("Total Items:" + count.ToString());
  } 
}
```

But it is always returning 0 as output. I'm using Version 3.5 of the IMAPX 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of emails in gmail using IMAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539692/count-number-of-emails-in-gmail-using-imap)

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539692/count-number-of-emails-in-gmail-using-imap

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Folder.Messages collection is not being filled. If you want to let the client download the messages automatically, configure the client do do this:

```
var client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", true);
client.Behavior.AutoPopulateFolderMessages = true;
```

However, it's often better to make a call to Folder.Messages.Download instead or use Folder.Search

[Documentation about message download mode..](https://imapx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20messages)

Comment: It is not the best way to download all the messages if you just need to get the number of messages in a folder. For this you can use the `Folder.Exists` property. Check my answer to this question on the [official forum](https://imapx.codeplex.com/discussions/553841)